# Един ли блок памяти Stack или их может быть несколько в одной программе?

Tags: java, память, стек

Един ли блок памяти Stack или их может быть несколько в одной программе?

### Собственно из чего вытекает вопрос:

> "Для выполнения в JVM создаётся основной поток (Thread). При создании потока ему выделяется **СВОЙ** стэк в памяти. Этот стэк состоит из фрэймов" JavaRush ©

Вот статья:

https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/609-prisvaivanie-i-inicializacija-v-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У каждого потока имеется свой стек. Всякий раз при создании нового потока (например с помощью `new Thread`) будет создан дополнительный стек, который закрепится за ним.

Для более глубокого изучения данного вопроса советую рассмотреть простейшие программы на `assembler` и попытаться написать пару тройку своих с переходом в процедуры.

Comment: А с Heap та же ситуация или куча едина и на "всех"?

Comment: она общая для всех, в этом суть отличия потоков от отдельных программ